# How to deal with the invalid date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I am trying to convert string in to date object in but I am getting two different result for two date. Help me to solve this issue and let me know is there any more convenient way to doing this.

```
<script>
  let date1 = '02-11-2022 17:32';
  let dateObj1 = new Date(date1);
  console.log(dateObj1); // Fri Feb 11 2022 17:32:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

  let date2 = "30-11-2022 17:32";
  let dateObj2 = new Date(date2);
  console.log(dateObj2); // Invalid Date
</script>
```

Comment: Those two dates are not the same ?? Why would you expect to not get two different results for two dates ??

Comment: @topsail I think OP means that they get a correct result for the first but "invalid date" for the second.

Comment: Yes, excatly @JaredSmith

Comment: See the linked dupe but TL;DR neither of your date string formats are correct, it's only coincidence that the first one works and there's no guarantee it will work on all implementations (e.g. it may work in Chrome but not FF or vice-versa).

Comment: Can you  plz sugget how can I convert this string into correct format @JaredSmith

Comment: In addition to the very thorough top answer on the linked dupe, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601